# PS / pytest - How Can I Datetime Stamp junitxml log (format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)?

Tags: powershell, pytest, command-line-interface

I'm running pytests and outputting to a junitxml using:

```
pytest -vv --junitxml="result.xml"
```

I would like the outfile to be parameterised to show the execution datetime of the tests so the file name looks like this for example:

```
"result_2023_10_30_01_00_00.xml"
```

Ideally I'd like to do this from the PowerShell CLI, but also open to using pytest config options but would need details about how to incorporate in my test_xxxxx.py / conftest.py modules because I'm new to pytest.

I've tried adding this to my test_xxxxx.py module so far but everything else remains unchanged:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    if not os.path.exists('reports'):
        os.makedirs('reports')
    config.option.htmlpath = 'reports/'+datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S")+".html"`
```

I've tried this with the junitxml CLI option and without, in case one was taking precedence over the other.

Comment: If this is a PowerShell command, try `--junitxml="result_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss')).xml"`

Comment: perfect, thanks @lit!

Comment: @lit I found this to be an enhancement in the format $((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss')) to make it chronological in the dir